# how to display span class field

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

i am trying to display two "text text-pass" from html  in chrome browser to my print console, apparently, it did not work, any advise please?

my browser html code

```
  <a href="/abc/123" class="active">
    <div class="sidebar-text"> 
     <span class="text text-pass"> </span> </a>
  <a href="/abc/1234" class="active">
        <div class="sidebar-text">
         <span class="text text-pass"> </span> </a>
```

My code

```
    String 123= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="js-app"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[5]/a")).getText();
    System.out.println(123);

String 1234= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="js-app"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[5]/a")).getText();
    System.out.println(1234);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.findElements` to get multiple elements with the same pattern, it will return a list collection.

**UPDATE**

Refers to your comment, you need put the string into a list again and check with the [Collection.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sidebar-text']//span"));
for(WebElement element: elements) {
    String attr = element.getAttribute("class");
    results.add(attr);
    System.out.println(attr);
}

if(results.contains("text text-fail")) {
    System.out.println("this is list contains 'text text-fail'");
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, sorry i am a total noob here, how do i display from the list to individual string? i have gotten 2 elements from the list and wish to put them into a string and one by one to verify

Comment: there are times when <span class="text text-pass"> may become <span class="text text-fail">, so my agenda here is to check if the list did not return any "text text-fail"

Comment: @user1579414 You need put the string into a `List` again, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code :

```
String pass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='sidebar-text']/span")).getAttribute("class");
System.out.println(pass);
```

Comment: Thanks saragada, but the code u provided didnt work, nothing has printed on the console. also how do i differentiate with ahref tag ? as i have two these ref tags. let me edit my post again

Comment: sorry i got it pasted wrongly, it works but however, how do i differentation with ahref tag? i need print both of spanclass text to verify that my ahref tag contains a pass for span class tag.